# Why does invoking R script using RScript works but not with R binary?

Tags: r, bash, macos, shebang

Is there something about the way she-bang works that I am missing?

```
# why does this not work?
§ ./sample.r 
./sample.r: line 3: 1: command not found

§ ll sample.r 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raghu.dodda staff 39 Jun 14 19:10 sample.r

§ cat sample.r
#!/usr/local/bin/r --slave -f 

1 + 1

# this is what the above command should effectively be doing; no?
§ /usr/local/bin/r --slave -f sample.r  
[1] 2
```

I am aware that the recommended way to run `r` scripts is to use `Rscript`, and if I change to that, it works. But, I am curious (for my own learning) why it does not work.

```
§ cat sample.r
#!/usr/local/bin/Rscript --vanilla 

1 + 1

§ ./sample.r 
[1] 2
```

A couple of other things if they matter:

**(1)** Both `r` and `R` are symlinked to the same place:

```
§ ls -l $(which r) $(which R)
lrwxr-xr-x 1 raghu.dodda admin 23 Jun 14 15:56 /usr/local/bin/R -> ../Cellar/r/4.0.1/bin/R
lrwxr-xr-x 1 raghu.dodda admin 23 Jun 14 15:56 /usr/local/bin/r -> ../Cellar/r/4.0.1/bin/R
```

**(2)** I installed `r` on my Mac using homebrew, i.e.,

```
brew install r
```

Comment: Your binary is probably `/usr/local/bin/R`, not `/usr/local/bin/r`. The latter is sometimes aliased to `R` (or to [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html), or in zsh it's a builtin to rerun the last command, etc.), but is not the R binary itself. That said, either works for me, so my configuration must differ from yours in some way.

Comment: And if `R` could be used directly for "#!" ("shebang") scripting then we would not have written [littler](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) and R Core would not have released `Rscript`.  Use those two.

Comment: @alistaire, I updated the question with some details; both `r` and `R` are symlinked to the same place. Thanks for checking on your machine; at least, helps me troubleshoot.

Comment: Are there any invisible characters hiding in the shebang line? Try viewing it with `LC_ALL=C cat -vt sample.r`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - Nope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the file symlinked by `/usr/local/bin/R` and `/usr/local/bin/r` is a **shell script**, and apparently, on macOS, this is a problem per the [Wikipedia entry for she-bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

> In Darwin-based operating systems such as macOS, and in Solaris, the file specified by interpreter must be an executable binary, and cannot itself be a script.

```
§ realpath $(which r)
/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.0.1/bin/R

§ file /usr/local/Cellar/r/4.0.1/bin/R
/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.0.1/bin/R: POSIX shell script text executable, ASCII text

§ head -2 /usr/local/Cellar/r/4.0.1/bin/R
#!/bin/sh
# Shell wrapper for R executable.
```

However, `Rscript` is a **binary**, and so it works as expected:

```
§ which Rscript
/usr/local/bin/Rscript

§ file /usr/local/bin/Rscript
/usr/local/bin/Rscript: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

On Linux, even if `r` were to symlink to a script (not sure if this is the case), it would work as expected based on this:

> On Linux and Minix, an interpreter can also be a script. A chain of shebangs and wrappers yields a directly executable file that gets the encountered scripts as parameters in reverse order.